# Prove $g(t) = \int_{\partial B_t} 1 d\sigma $ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be defined as $g(t) = \int_{\partial B_t} 1 d\sigma $, with $B_t$ the ball centered at the origin with radius $t>0$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Prove $g$ is continuous.

Intuitively I can see why that's true - if we change the radius by "a small amount" then the length of the sphere also changes by "a small amount".

My current progress:
For all $t>0$ we can define $G: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ as $G(x) = \frac{x}{t}$. This is a radial vector field so the normal $\hat n$ at each point in $\partial B_t$ is $\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert}$, but $\lVert x \rVert = t$ when $x \in \partial B_t$. Now, observe that:

$$ \int_{\partial B_t} \langle G, \hat n \rangle d\sigma = \int_{\partial B_t} \langle \frac{x}{t}, \frac{x}{t} \rangle d\sigma = \int_{\partial B_t} \frac{1}{t^2} \lVert x \rVert^2 d\sigma = \int_{\partial B_t}1 d\sigma = g(t)
$$

But by the Divergence Theorem:

$$
\int_{\partial B_t} \langle G, \hat n \rangle d\sigma = \int_{B_t} div(G)dx = \int_{B_t}\frac{n}{t}dx = g(t)
$$

Since $DG_x = \frac{1}{t}I_n$.

Now, I want to use epsilon-delta definition to show $|g(t)-g(s)|<\epsilon$ when $|t-s|<\delta$ but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You could try to calculate the surface integral of the $n$-sphere of radius $t$ to find the explicit formula $2 \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)} t^{n-1},$ this is continuous in $t$ by a quick inspection.

Comment: @F_M_ Thank you! Although I don't think I have the tools to do that yet. I've only just learned about integration over smooth manifolds, the divergence theorem and vector fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change-of-variables theorem (which comes before learning about manifolds and divergence/Stokes theorem) is I think the best way to go. Depending on how you develop things, you can prove abstractly a version of the change-of-variables theorem at the manifold level (which is a consequence of the usual $\Bbb{R}^n$ version), in which case you find that $g(t)=t^{n-1}\cdot\int_{\partial B_1}1\,d\sigma$. You don’t need the exact value of the constant (the surface area of $S^{n-1}$); all you need is that the dependence is $t^{n-1}$, and hence smooth.

---

Alternatively, continuing from where you left off using the divergence theorem, we have by the change-of-variables theorem in $\Bbb{R}^n$, that
\begin{align}
g(t)&=\int_{B_t}\frac{n}{t}\,dx=\int_{B_1}\frac{n}{t}\cdot t^n\,dy=nt^{n-1}\int_{B_1}1\,dy,
\end{align}
so again this gives you a $t^{n-1}$ dependence (and in fact using this, you get a formula for how the volume of $B_1$ is related to the surface area of $S^{n-1}=\partial B_1$).

---

There is no way to get an “elementary”, low-tech proof of continuity, because you’re integrating over a ball (which is curved), not a rectangle or something simple. So, you’re going to need some sort of theorem which tells you how limits behave with the region of integration.

For example, it suffices to show that $v(t)=\int_{B_t}1\,dx$ is a continuous function on $(0,\infty)$, so that $g(t)=\frac{n}{t}v(t)$ being the product of continuous functions is also continuous. To prove $v$ is continuous, fix $(r_0,x_0)\in (0,\infty)$ and consider the indicator function $\chi_{B_{r_0}(x_0)}$ of the ball $B_{r_0}(x_0)$ of radius $r_0>0$ and center $x_0\in\Bbb{R}^n$. Then, as $(r,x)\to (r_0,x_0)$, we have that $\chi_{B_r(x)}\to \chi_{B_{r_0}(x_0)}$ pointwise on $\Bbb{R}^n\setminus S_{r_0}(x_0)$, where $S_{r_0}(x_0)$ is the sphere $\partial B_{r_0}(x_0)$ of radius $r_0$ and center $x_0$. However, spheres have $n$-dimensional measure zero (a little annoying to prove, but not too bad, if you know some basic facts like graphs of continuous functions have measure zero). Hence the convergence of the indicator functions holds pointwise a.e.

With all this said, Lebesgue’s dominated convergence theorem can now be applied to deduce continuity of $v$ (actually the argument shows that for any $f\in L^1_{loc}(\Bbb{R}^n)$, the function $(r,x)\mapsto \int_{B_r(x)}f(y)\,dy$ is continuous… i.e integrating makes things nicer).

Comment: Thank you! I actually did end up using the change of variables theorem to show the relation between the volume of a ball with radius $t$ to the unit ball.